# MATLAB: How to determine whether any elements of an array are a certain a number

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am creating a simple minesweeper game for an assignment, but I am having trouble making the program determine whether the player has won or not. I am trying to find a function that determines whether any of the elements of A are equal to -2 and then use that in a while loop.

I have a simplified test code that I have been using to try to do this, but I can't find any functions that do what I want to do.

With everything I've tried so far, it either just keeps asking for more input even when it should say that the game is over, or it skips the while loop entirely. The last thing probably happens because all the elements of the start array are equal.

I have looked at xor, unique, setdiff, intersect, ismember isempty, and probably a couple more that I can't remember.

As this is not the complete code, I have just answered yes to the flag question every time in order to change all the elements from -2 to -3.

I also know that this wouldn't be the best way to determine whether the player has won or not, as it doesn't take into consideration if all the flags are placed correctly, but I wanna sort this part out first before I get on to that:)

```
A=zeros(2)
selected=0;
flag=-3

for r=1:2
    for c=1:2
        A(r,c)==-2;
    end
end

while % any of the elements in A are equal to -2
    while selected~=-1 
        selectRow=input('Which row is the cell you would like to access on? ');
        selectCol=input('Which column is the cell you would like to access on? ');
        selectFlag=input('Would you like to put a flag in this cell? ','s');
        if selectRow<=2 && selectRow>=1 && selectCol<=2 && selectCol>=1
            while strcmp(selectFlag, 'yes') || strcmp(selectFlag, 'no')
                if strcmp(selectFlag, 'yes')
                    A(selectRow,selectCol)=flag;
                    disp(A);
                elseif strcmp(selectFlag, 'no')
                    selected=mineBoard(selectRow,selectCol);
                    A(selectRow,selectCol)=selected;
                    disp(A);
                end
            end
        end
    end
fprintf('You have hit a mine. Please restart.\n');
end

fprintf('Congrats! You have won!');
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`any`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function

Comment: `any( A == -2 )` is probably what you want. Please note this question would be greatly improved if you made the pre-amble more concise, and added comments to your code to explain what it does, what it's *supposed* to do, and why you have issues. Looks like you'll get an infinite loop for your inner `while` too, because you don't change the value of `selectFlag` anywhere in the loop, so once it's true it will be true forever.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to know if an entry of `A` is equal to -2 and how to interact with the location of all those entries.

**The [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function**
As suggested by @[etmuse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8559235/etmuse) and @[Wolfie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3978545/wolfie) in the comments, the [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function may be best here. Notice in the documentation that more advanced options are available for versions R2018b and later.

```
% MATLAB R2017a
rng(8675309)                % For reproducibility (ensure some -2 appear)
A = randi([-4 0],4)         % Generate example matrix
any(A == -2,1)              % Test columns of A
any(A == -2,2)              % Test rows of A
```

**Logical Index**

```
% Use a logical index
idx = (A == -2)
```

**Indices**
It is a bit trickier to use the indices.

```
% Use the indices directly.
ind = find(A==-2)
```

Notice this gives you the indices if the array `A` were converted to vector form.

```
A(:)                            % Force column vector
reshape(A(:),4,4)'              % Reshape into matrix
```

---

Disclosure:  If @etmuse or @Wolfie post answer with `any` function, will remove that from my answer or make this community wiki.  It was their idea.